# Matic address for polygon.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote

Tags: 0x

Good morning,
I use the API of 0x and more precisely this route:https://polygon.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote

I do not understand why we must use the address 0XEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEED TO MATIC instead of 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000101010101010101010101010101010

while exchanges like uniswap use: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000001010

thanks in advance